# Visualforce Javascript Selectors Becoming Undefined After Rerender

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, rerender

I have a VF Page that renders several "tabs" of data. On initial load it works exactly as expected, but then if I use a pagereference method on a button or event I then `rerender` the page, unfortunately once I rerender the tabs are now broken.

I've attempted **onComplete**:

```
<apex:actionSupport oncomplete="resettabs()" action="{!doStuff}" 
                                             reRender="page" status="loadingData"/>
```

I've tried **onStop**:

```
<apex:actionStatus id="loadingData" onstop="resettabs()">
```

The `resettabs()` contains an alert, this fires as expected (onload and onStop/Complete), but it appears the jquery selector went from finding "tab1" to `undefined` -- this based on the selector (`$('.tabgroup > div')`)

I've also added the call to my `<apex:actionStatus onstop="resettabs()">` which led to similar results. It appears that either way, no matter how I attempt it, the JS is called before the elements that are being rerendered are loaded.

Here is the JS in the `<head>` (also tried it in the `<apex:outputPanel id="page">` which is the

```
<script>
 $ = jQuery.noConflict();
 $(document).ready(function(){
    resettabs();
 });

 function resettabs(){
    $('.tabgroup > div').hide();
    $('.tabgroup > div:first-of-type').show();
    $('.tabs a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            tabgroup = '#'+$this.parents('.tabs').data('tabgroup'),
            others = $this.closest('li').siblings().children('a'),
            target = $this.attr('href');
        others.removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        $(tabgroup).children('div').hide();
        $(target).show();
    });
 }
 </script>
```

**Debug Results:**
With this `alert($('.tabgroup > div').attr('id'));` message in the resettabs() I get the following debug results

- On page loading: **"tab1"**
- Running resettabs() from JS console: **"tab1"**
- After rerender: **"undefined"**
- Running resettabs() from JS after rerender: **"undefined"**

Comment: can you share more code ? Oncomplete call all jquery functions again .

Comment: Basically .. What you need once your rerender performed oncomplete of the action function again you need to initialize/ rerender javascript as well.

Comment: How would I do that? I've attempt putting it within the rerendered section believing it would do that but it doesn't work.

Comment: you are doing correct oncomplete of action function calling `resettabs` function should work..

Comment: When the page first load its called using `$(document).ready()` which waits till the elements on the page are rendered. Is it possible that _oncomplete_ is called prior to the rerendering of those elements? Or more likely that the selectors cannot be obtained that way dynamically after the rerender? (looking at debug results posted I'm leaning towards the latter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AH HA!** I figured it out. Realized that not only were my tabs not hiding/showing/functioning after the rerender but some of the tabs were out of place. Closer look revealed that what is happening is my *.tabgroup class* was on a `<section>` **html5 tag**.

With that I googled and found this helpful tip:

[HTML5 elements vanish when rerendering Visualforce **(*a bug with reRender (VF) removing HTML 5 tags*)**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/923/10834)

That led me to obviously **convert the `<section>` tags to `<div>` tags** and now my `oncomplete` action works as expected. Thanks for the comments along the way which helped me stay the course I was on.